# Align 16 small images in a 4 x 4 grid

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment

Does anybody know, how I can allign 16 images like a grid with 4 columns and 4 rows?

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\subfloat[0,1 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{25.gif}}&
\subfloat[25 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{26.gif}}&
\subfloat[750 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{27.gif}}&
\subfloat[1618,55 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{28.gif}}\\
\subfloat[0,1 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{29.gif}}&
\subfloat[25 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{30.gif}}&
\subfloat[750 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{31.gif}}&
\subfloat[1618,55 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{32.gif}}\\
\subfloat[0,1 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{33.gif}}&
\subfloat[25 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{34.gif}}&
\subfloat[750 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{35.gif}}&
\subfloat[1618,55 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{36.gif}}\\
\subfloat[0,1 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{37.gif}}&
\subfloat[25 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{38.gif}}&
\subfloat[750 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{39.gif}}&
\subfloat[1618,55]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{40.gif}}\\
\subfloat[0,1 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{41.gif}}&
\subfloat[25 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{42.gif}}&
\subfloat[750 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{43.gif}}&
\subfloat[1618,55 s]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{44.gif}}&
\end{tabular}
\caption{4 x 5}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Do they have the same dimensions? Shall they fit on one page?

Comment: Do they need captions? If so, should they be treated as independent figures or as subfigures?

Comment: @UweZiegenhagen yes they all have the same height. The last image in each row has a smaller width. And yes I need captions which are not long and fit under each image.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina yes with captions, but they are very short and can fit centered under each image.

Answer (score 25):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}}\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}}\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}}\\
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subfloat[caption]{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}}
\end{tabular}
\caption{4 x 4}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

By using the figure environment and tabular inside, you can achieve your results.

[image]

If you are using the `subcaption` package, you can do this:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\subcaptionbox{caption\label{1}}{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subcaptionbox{caption\label{2}}{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subcaptionbox{caption\label{1}}{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}} &
\subcaptionbox{caption\label{2}}{\includegraphics[width = 1.5in]{something}}\\
...
\end{tabular}
\caption{caption}
\label{3}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm always getting the error `undefined control sequence´. Does this have anything to fo with `&´ and ´\\`?

Comment: I added my code to the question. I don't see anything missing. Can you please check?

Comment: @abdu remove the last `&`

Comment: I removed it and tried but it didn't work. I must say, I'm not using the `subfigure` package because I'm using the `subcaption` package and both conflict with each other.

Comment: Thank you, I saw this in an another post and it works. Can I put this in a minipage environment? Because I need it centre the whole grid alone on the page.

Comment: @abdu I believe so.  You can always float the figure and it should be placed on its own page due to its size.

Comment: Using the first approach, the captions aren't aligned to center under the subfigures. How could I fix this?

Comment: I had to add an additional `\` that results in `\\`. I was getting errors about `\cr` but I do believe that it was because my figure was inside a `frame` environment (I'm using this in a beamer presentation).

Comment: Thanks alot for this very helpful answer. Can we use `\hyperref`? I'm unable to use it