# Grid of images without cations and equal space vertical and horizontal?

Tags: tables, graphics, diagrams, grids

[Previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122486/how-to-insert-a-fixed-number-of-figures-per-row-column) [questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122786/align-16-small-images-in-a-4-x-4-grid) about images in a grid have captions and does not have equal distance horizontally and vertically.

I would like to make this grid, without the text and background. It is taken from [here](https://stackshare.io/).

[image]

**Question**

Does anyone know how to make such a grid of 24x24 images?

**Update**

If I do the following, then I can't get the same distance horizontally and vertically...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=raggedright}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-a}}\\
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\hfill
{\includegraphics[width=.18\textwidth,height=2cm]{example-image-b}}\\
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [One of the ones you linked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122515/107497) uses minipages to space things appropriately.  Within those minipages, captions are a separate command that can be easily removed.  Does that get you your answer?

Comment: @Teepeemm I have just tried, and updated OP. Can't get the distances to be equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the naming scheme of your images is `image-<col>-<row>.png` you can make a grid of images with tikz via a nested `foreach` loop.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\begin{figure}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=\linewidth/24, y=\linewidth/24]

        \foreach \i in {1,...,24} {
            \foreach \j in {1,...,24} {
                \node[
                    rounded corners = 2pt,
                    minimum width   = \linewidth/24-3pt,
                    minimum height  = \linewidth/24-3pt,
                    inner sep       = 0pt,
                    fill            = black,
                    font            = \scriptsize,
                    text            = white
                ] at (\i,-\j) {\i x\j%
                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                    % \includegraphics[width=\linewidth/24-5pt]{image-\i-\j.png}}
                    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
                };
            }
        }

    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Grid of images}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```